# Databases not created when running code coverage with paratest

Tags: laravel, phpunit, code-coverage, parallel-testing

My app is a Laravel app and I am wanting to leverage paratest to generate my code coverage reports.

My tests run fine in parallel using:

```
php artisan test --parallel
```

I couldn't see a way to use the artisan command to run code coverage so am using paratest directly. The command I want to use is:

```
XDEBUG_MODE=coverage vendor/bin/paratest -p16 --coverage-text --verbose --runner=WrapperRunner
```

However this results in the following:

```
Running phpunit in 16 processes with /var/www/myapp/dev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit

Configuration read from /var/www/myapp/dev/phpunit.xml

EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  63 / 176 ( 35%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE 126 / 176 ( 71%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE...............WRRRWW              176 / 176 (100%)

Time: 00:14.540, Memory: 18.00 MB

There were 155 errors:

1) Tests\Feature\MyTest::it_does_something
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table...

(and further down)

2) Tests\Feature\MyOtherTest::it_does_something_else
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'migrations' already exists...
```

Just a note that if I run coverage normally, this works using:

```
XDEBUG_MODE=coverage vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-filter ./src/app --coverage-html ./coverage --path-coverage --coverage-cache ./coverage-cache
```

The database used for testing is MySQL. I couldn't use SQLite as I needed to use a specific function present in MySQL but not SQLite (namely - YEARWEEK). My `phpunit.xml` (if useful) is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         forceCoversAnnotation="true"
         beStrictAboutCoversAnnotation="true"
         beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true"
         beStrictAboutTodoAnnotatedTests="true"
         colors="true"
         verbose="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </coverage>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql-test"/>
        <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: To be honest, I have never run tests in parallel, but it seems there is something wrong with it, so my personal recommendation would be to not run tests in parallel... how much time do you save parallel vs not parallel ?

Comment: Its probably about 20/30 seconds just running tests but coverage can take a couple of minutes to run which is what I was hoping to shave down a little. The project is growing as well so this time is increasing. When I have more free time, I will get to grips with it. Just wondered if there was a simple fix or I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is already an old thread, I found it today because I figured out the same issue... and maybe somebody else comes later and this could help.

In my case I'm just using Pest PHP and always called the pest command directly, without using artisan test. Since Pest 2 I'm now facing the same errors as above - missing base tables.

Since this quesion here didn't help me, I continued searching and found this blog post:
https://sarahjting.com/blog/laravel-paratest-multiple-db-connections

and that brought me to the "simple" solution to just use "artisan test --parallel"

In meanwhile you can use coverage with artisan, so it should't be a problem any more for you.

```
XDEBUG_MODE=coverage php artisan test --parallel --processes=16 --coverage-text --verbose
```

Until this I wasn't really aware that it really makes a difference if I use artisan test or vendor/bin/pest directly.